# MVYSideMenu IN iOS 7 hides status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, mvysidemenu

I am using [MVYSideMenu](https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu) in my application. It is working really good, the problem is that in iOS7 when the menu is open, the status bar is mixed with the menu. I have solved this by setting the TableView y position 20 pt down, but this solution is not the best, because in iOS 6 it is different. I am new in iOS and even more in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the status bar setting UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO in Info.plist

Comment: thank you for solution. I have one last question pls is it possible to disable the side view controller for some viewcontroller